# Fresh reinstall of VS 2022 Community on Windows 11 fails

Tags: visual-studio-2022

1. Checked every .NET Framework installation on Windows 11 (Programs and Features, each one listed and repairable - repaired)
2. Re-installed all .NET Cores (3.1 to 8.0)
3. Totally removed VS2022, incl. installer (incl. deleting `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Visual...`)
4. Cleared MEF cache and all in AppData
5. Downloaded installer
6. Installed VS2022 with a single workload - ASP.NET
   (back to 1-6 several times sometimes incl. registry keys which are not expected to cause severe penalties)

And the reward is:

[image]

Asked VS Support (still waiting for an answer).

Any ideas?

This is what MEF (?) scanned and reported in `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_a7dda8f3\ComponentModelCache\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.scan`:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\INTELLICODE\IntelliCodeCpp.dll;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\XAMLLANGUAGESERVICE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlUpgradeAssistant.dll;Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.VCPlugin.dll;Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\nuget\NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.dll;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

and this is what failed (`C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_a7dda8f3\ComponentModelCache\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err`):

```
----- Catalog construction errors ----- Error #1 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.Cpp.CppIntelliCodeProvider+<InitializeAsync>d__6".
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)    at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Error #2 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.Cpp.CppIntelliCodeProvider+<RefreshReadyStateAsync>d__14".
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(RuntimeType type)    at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(Type partType, Boolean typeExplicitlyRequested)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Type type)    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Error #3 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: ReflectionTypeLoadException while enumerating types in assembly "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\INTELLICODE\IntelliCodeCpp.dll". Results will be incomplete. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()    at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<CreateAssemblyDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(Assembly a)    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.RecommendationProvider, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : IntelliCodeCpp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
...
```

(Rest omitted because perhaps the above is enough.)

Comment: Manually deleting the install folder is not a good idea.  Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#remove-all-with-installcleanupexe)

Comment: @HansPassant: Tried. No luck. This is the notorious DCOM! Or COM, whatever.